# How to refresh firebase access_token using next-auth credentials provider?

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, next-auth

I wanted to know how i can refresh the firebase access token when it expires. I need the access token for api authentication. I have tried to find it online but can't seem to find anything with next-auth and firebase.

This is what i have right now. I am able to get the access token just not able to refresh when it expires. So after some time i get the api authentication error.

```
import { auth } from "@/config/firebaseApp";
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  pages: {
    signIn: "/signIn",
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      type: "credentials",
      credentials: {},
      authorize: async (credentials): Promise<any> => {
        return await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          auth,
          (credentials as any).email || "",
          (credentials as any).password || ""
        )
          .then(async (userCredentials) => {
            const dummy = {
              role: "admin",
            };

            if (userCredentials.user) {
              return {
                ...userCredentials.user,
                role: dummy.role || "user",
                access_token: await userCredentials.user.getIdToken(),
              };
            }
            return null;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
          });
      },
    }),
  ],

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.role = user.role;
        token.access_token = user.access_token;
      }
      return token;
    },

    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (session.user) {
        session.user.role = token.role;
      }

      return session;
    },
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Also I am a beginner so correct me if I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

The Firebase Authentication SDK automatically refreshes the ID token about 5 minutes before it expires, and `getIdToken()` always gives you the latest token. Since Firebase ID tokens are valid for an hour, the token you get from `getIdToken` should be valid for at least 5 minutes and up to 60 minutes.

You can pass this token to your own backend to [validate it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) there. You can also cache the token there, but **you should not associate the decoded token with the user/UID**.

An approach that many of Firebase's own connectionless services take:

1. Always pass the ID token with any API call you make from the client.
2. Have a cache on the server of encoded ID tokens, and decoded values.
3. Verify any ID tokens which don't exists in the cache yet, and cache the result.
4. Expunge items from the cache that are older than an hour.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. But, still not sure where to access getIdToken() method other than in authorize function in the above code. This method is called only once in the authorize function, so i only get the token once on login.

Comment: You should call `getIdToken()` every time you need to ppass the otkenb to the server.

Comment: Still not clear. My concern is that where am i going to use the getIdToken method, since i am not able to access it anywhere outside the authorize function. And it is only getting called once on successful authentication/login.